# What NOREPLACE means at netflix's nebula plugin?

Tags: gradle, netflix-nebula-plugins

I was using netflix's nebula. Looking [here](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/wiki/RPM-Plugin), I saw this line:

```
fileType [org.freecompany.redline.payload.Directive] - Default for types, e.g. CONFIG, DOC, NOREPLACE, LICENSE
```

I didn't find any doc about the actual meaning of this enum, but I've found [the original code](http://ftp.rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/rpmlib_8h.html#a971f2ba87d2d6dad4105eac2499df63).

Now I want an actual description of this enum. I thought NOREPLACE is releated to being not allowed to replace the file. But I want to be sure and don't rely on assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I have only seen `noreplace` as an additional attribute on a `config` file, *e.g.* `%config(noreplace)`. It means that if the user has edited the file, the installer should put its new version as `filename.rpmnew`; by default `%config` files are replaced with the user one put as `filename.rpmold` .